# JVM proxy parameters reset overnight?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, jakarta-ee, proxy

I have a problem on a Java application we recently migrated to an Azure platform. The app runs on a Tomcat and is deployed automatically via Ansible. The application needs to make some HTTP calls to an API through a proxy, so we pass the proxy parameters in the setenv.sh, here are the parts of code :

vars :

```
tomcat_java_options:
  - 'https.proxyHost=xx.xx.xx.xx'
  - 'https.proxyPort=8080'
```

setenv:

```
{% if tomcat_java_options is defined %}
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS {{ '-D'~tomcat_java_options|join(' -D') }}"
{% endif %}
```

The problem is : each morning, the requests that should pass through the proxy are timing out. We can see with netstat that the request is going directly to the API without passing through the proxy. On the server, we can join the API via curl (with the proxy). 
The problem is resolved by restarting the tomcat, until the next morning.

Do someone have en explanation ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As long as the proxy is available and working (a connection through it doesn't fail) `Tomcat` will use it. After an invalid proxy connection it will not be used anymore (until restart, of course). Are you sure there aren't any problems on the proxy during the night?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems a good explanation but unfortunately I don't see any errors in the logs that are not related to a timeout. I will ask the proxy team if there is any downtime.